# jquery: How to know if a page is not in focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if user is doing other things but not viewing this page, jquery/javascript can know?

I don't need to be very accurate, just roughly.

Comment: `not viewing this page`. What exactly do you mean by this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(window).focus(function(){
  // back in focus
});
```

And:

```
$(window).blur(function(){
  // no focus 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use a `blur` or `focusout` event on your `document` or `window`.

```
$(document).bind('focusout', function() {
    // window or tab just lost the focus
});
```

that's using jQuery. You should play around with this, also use the window object as target. I'm not super sure how cross-browser this works, but it should perform well.

Comment: Seems less stable at the document level than at the window level, according to this document: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html